# Parse-server app not working gcloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, parse-platform, google-cloud-platform, parse-server

I have server based backend deployed on app engine and it's working(free trial), but it have too much resources. I want to deploy an updated version of it with more fine tuned app.yaml and some minor updates. The problem is: new version is not working. It have some redirect code and it works, when i directly type:
https://myapp/parse
it shows:

> {"error":"unauthorized"}

it's all good.
But when i try to do login, or other CRUD it just writing logs and doesn't do anything.

Because of that all i can do is return traffic to old version, which is working just fine, and beg for help.
May be google did some updates in last month and i have to redo something in my app?

**UPD**

Backend always returns 307 redirect when i do authorized request, old(deployed in november 16) version works great.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear for me the issue. If it is possible to show us the whole output.

But apparently, it is the HTTPS in your URL. Try it with HTTP. It is the most common scenario for the unauthorized error.

Comment: {"error":"unauthorized"} - indicator of that the backend is functioning somehow, it's good. When i do authorized call i get 307 redirect